# sfdx-mohanc-plugins error

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, saql, data-set

I'm getting

**Error: yarn add sfdx-mohanc-plugins@latest --non-interactive --mutex=file:C:\Users\User-S\AppData\Local\sfdx\yarn.lock --preferred-cache-folder=C:\Users\User-S\AppData\Local\sfdx\yarn --check-files exited with code 1**

While installing sfdx-mohanc-plugins.

I followed all the procedure mentioned in **https://www.salesforceblogger.com/2020/11/17/mohans-sfdx-plugin-for-analytics/** .

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Tried running `sfdx plugins:install -v sfdx-mohanc-plugins` to get some more verbose output? That might give some more context, because as it stands the error you've quoted doesn't really give much information to go on.

Comment: @Dave I installed the latest **node.js** package then I installed **Salesforce CLI** after that I run the command **sfdx plugins:install sfdx-mohanc-plugins**. Then I'm getting the above error.

Comment: Yeah, so if you try with the `-v` flag you might get some further detail around where the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be resolved by ensuring yarn is installed globally. I had previously run into a similar issue when trying to update plugins and would get an "exited with code 1" message.

`npm install --global yarn`